# Half Clique Property question

Tags: algorithms, graphs, clique

Hey I had this question and am stuck on part (b).

I don't see how its possible to find a graph with 7 vertices and 15 edges that does **not** have the half-clique problem. If there is a way, could someone share their thought process rather than the answer as I would like to figure it out on my own.

Thanks a lot!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider a clique $C$ with vertex-set $V = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$. $C$ has $\binom{7}{2} = \frac{6 \cdot 7}{2} = 21$ edges.

For any $S \subseteq V$ with $|S| \ge \lceil V/2\rceil =4$, either:

- $S$ contains at least two vertices in $\{1,2,3\}$; or
- $S$ contains at least $2$ vertices in $\{4,5,6\}$.

From the above it should be easy to construct the desired graph.

> You can simply delete all the edges between vertices that are both in $\{1,2,3\}$ or both in $\{4,5,6\}$ to obtain a graph that has $21- 2 \cdot \binom{3}{2} = 21 - 2 \cdot 3 = 15$ edges and does not have the half-clique property.